# without any arguments, what does `ssh-agent` do?

Tags: ssh

without any arguments, what does `ssh-agent` do?

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent says:

> Start the ssh-agent in the background.
>
> ```
> $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 59566
> ```

What is the purpose of starting it by `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` instead of `ssh-agent`?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `ssh-agent -s` do?  What is the output?  What happens when you `eval` it?  What changes?  You _know_ the answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ssh-agent` command on its own starts an SSH agent and **prints the variable assignments needed for SSH commands to talk to that agent.** Since you need to *run* the variable assignments to actually set the variables you need to `eval` the output.

This is the only known example of a good use of `eval`.